# symfony 3 iteration of array of objects too long

Tags: php, symfony

I got an array of symfony3 entities which is 50000 in total. I need to iterate  this array and find some entities that match certain criteria. 
 code is shown below:

```
$p_r = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product_region')->findall();//50000 elements in array
$rowid_2 = $product->getRowId();//some product entity

foreach($p_r as $pr){
   $rowid_1 = $pr->getProductid()->getRowId();

   if($rowid_1 == $rowid_2){
     $regions[] = $pr->getRegionid()->getName();
     $filial_name = $pr->getRegionid()->getFilial()->getName();

     if(!in_array($filial_name, $filials)){
       $filials[] =  $filial_name;
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is when iteration takes approx 1 second which is very long.it takes about 25% of a CPU 1 core to finish the operation. I tested it on a different array of numbers and observed  it took about 0.002 sec to iterate through 50 000 elements. Any ideas how to speed it up and where to search for a delay would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: In my experience it's best not to use objects when working with large amounts of data.

Comment: Why not do the comparison in the db? Also, why are you handling ids, normally you'd let doctrine handle them. It's rarely a good idea to use them directly.

Comment: should I convert it to array and make a search in array? If I have a foreign key relation in the entity, how can I reach that connected entity without object?

Comment: as @Yousi already said, you should select from DB only what you need. Don't do this in the PHP side, just specify the condition in the query itself.

Comment: Don't do it in the PHP side, do it in database side

Comment: It looks like you are using lazy loading which means that you are kicking off a gazillion queries.  For example, each $pr->getRegionid()->getFilial()->getName(); is probably querying for a region object and then doing another query for a filial object.  You can look at how to write a custom query to eager load this sort of stuff.  However, as the other folks suggest, this is better done by creating a specific database query.

Comment: What Cerad said.  Look at joining the entity to turn 50,000 queries into 1, and also use the database to do that work, where it's better-suited.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to find some entities that match certain criteria You could use Doctrine's 2 Criteria to fetch those entities.

I found it really usefull. Here you have link to Doctrine's docs:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Create a Region/Product [Symfony Repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) and craft a `finder` function using [QueryBuilder/DQL](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/docs/en/reference/query-builder.rst) that you can specify the ID you're searching for OR use the ArrayCollection functions and Criteria to filter your results.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('product_id', $product_id))->setFirstResult(0);
$items = $p_r->matching($criteria);
```

Iterating (foreach) over that array of objects will trigger lazy loading which will hog CPU/Memory.  Check out the code for Doctrine [ArrayCollections](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) and [Criteria](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections)